# binding the wrong template class method using boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost

There is a base class `asio_handler`:

the `class T>` is the type defining boost::asio socket (plain text, or the wrapped around ssl)

```
template <class T> asio_handler:
{
    // ...
    asio_handler(const std::shared_ptr<T> sock)
    : socket_(sock)
    {}

    // this method handles connections
    void do_connect(const boost::system::error_code & err)
    {
        boost::asio::async_read_until(*socket_,
                                      http_response::buffer_,
                                      rn_,
                                      boost::bind(&asio_handler<T>::read_status_line, 
                                                  this, 
                                                  boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void read_status_line(const boost::system::error_code & err)
    {
         // same as before, binding to an asio_handler<T>::method
    }

private:
    const std::shared_ptr<T> socket_;
};
```

One of the inheriting classes is asio_http which uses an `http_socket`:

```
typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket http_socket;
class asio_http : public asio_handler<http_socket>
{
    // ... construct appropriately

    void connect(const boost::system::error_code err)
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(*socket_,
                                     request_,
                                     boost::bind(&asio_handler<http_socket>::do_request<http_socket>, 
                                                 this,
                                                 boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
};
```

The issue appears to be that the template class method being bound is unknown? (Unless I miss-understood, which wouldn't surprise me).

```
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:22: error: type 'void (rapp::cloud::asio_handler<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >::*)(const
      boost::system::error_code &)' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
    typedef typename F::result_type type;
                     ^
```

Which seems to be related to:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:15:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (rapp::cloud::asio_handler<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,
      boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >::*)(const boost::system::error_code &)>' requested here
    typedef typename result_traits<R, F>::type result_type;
```

Which propagates from all the callbacks being bound by the inheriting class towards the base class callbacks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Asio isn't actually relevant to your problem.

Comment: What if you try `boost::bind<void>(&asio_handler<http_socket>::do_request, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error)`?

Comment: @Barry, thanks I will but this is going to take some time.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60e4fd9e90209bbc).  `boost::bind` is fine with templates; your problem must lie elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @MilesBudnek could you please provide a simple example where you use boost::bind to bind a template class method as callback?

Comment: [Here you go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a797efefe2d35aa).  It's not significantly different than my previous example though.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Many thanks! That is what I've been doing, so I guess you're right, the error is someplace else.

Comment: @aschepler doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This extremely cryptic error I posted above, was produced by:

`Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`

Trying to compile the same code under Ubuntu/GCC produced a more helpful error:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (rapp::cloud::asio_handler<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::*)(const boost::system::error_code&)>’:
```

Googling around I found [this blog post](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/cpp-boost-bind-not-struct-error.html) which explains that the error is simply that the method signature does not match the placeholders.

Indeed that was the case, the solution was simple:

```
void read_content(
                  const boost::system::error_code & err,
                  const std::size_t bytes
                 );
```

I really hope this will help somebody stuck at this like me, the error was silly but the produced error message was hard to decypher.

Ultimately it was my mistake since the [boost::asio::async_read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html) function is clear on the parameters.